# Angular fullcalendar requiring two clicks to open modal when clicking event

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, angular6

I am using Angular6 and a dialog component and Angular FullCalendar. I have a working calendar. I am trying to achieve the following behaviour: When I click once on an event, a dialog box should open with some details on the event. Currently, when an event is clicked, it doesn't load the first time, but only after a second click. For example, an event is clicked, nothing appears, you click again anywhere on the screen and the modal appears. The actual `openModal` function finishes before the second click. Does it have something to do with the injection of the `ModalComponent` in the `openModal` function?

Calendar component:
TS:

```
this.calendarOptions = {
  height:500,
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: false,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
  },
  eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
    let data = {
      title: calEvent.title,
      start: calEvent.start,
      end: calEvent.end,
      price: calEvent.price,
      subject: calEvent.subject,
      subtotal: calEvent.price,
      b_id: calEvent.b_id
    };
    this.openModal(data);
  }
}

openModal(data) {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.data = data;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="calendar-container">
  <angular2-fullcalendar #calendar [options]="calendarOptions" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

Modal code:
TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  @Input() public data;

  ngOnInit() {

   console.log(this.data)
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div role="document" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          {{ data.title }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I have scoured the Internet for a solution to this issue, but, for the life of me cannot figure out a solution. Can anyone help? Is there a way to call the `openModal` function from the HTML side. I tried `(click)="openModal"`, but there is no way to get the actual specific event data.

Any help or suggestions on this?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz reproducable example?

Comment: @JonnySprouse why you dont have `@Input() initialized` defined? Is it valid attribute for calendar?

Comment: Why would I need `@Input initialized`?